# Scene Time to Fraction Node

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics

I have an example where I have the *Scene Time* output connected to the math node *Fraction* and the output of the *Fraction* node connected to the *Factor* attribute of the *Sample Curve*.

I am trying to understand how this works.

The output *Seconds* of *Scene Time* is by definition the current scene time. The current scene time is probably the elapsed time, which should be an increasing integer? What is the output of the *Fraction* node in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Scene Time` node outputs the seconds as a float value at the *Seconds* output.

The `Math` node with the setting *Fraction* returns the decimal places of a float value.

To better explain *Fraction*, I'll assume a frame rate of 24fps, and present the values in tabular form:

| Frame | Seconds | Fraction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 48 | 2.0 (because ${48\over24} = 2$) | 0.0 |
| 49 | 2.042 (because ${49\over24} = 2.041666...$) | 0.042 |
| 50 | 2.083 (because ${50\over24} = 2.083333...$) | 0.083 |
| 51 | 2.125 | 0.125 |
| 52 | 2.167 | 0.167 |
| 53 | 2.208 | 0.208 |
| 54 | 2.25 | 0.25 |
| 55 | 2.292 | 0.292 |
| 56 | 2.333 | 0.333 |
| 57 | 2.375 | 0.375 |
| 58 | 2.417 | 0.417 |
| 59 | 2.458 | 0.458 |
| 60 | 2.5 | 0.5 |
| 61 | 2.542 | 0.542 |
| 62 | 2.583 | 0.583 |
| 63 | 2.625 | 0.625 |
| 64 | 2.667 | 0.667 |
| 65 | 2.708 | 0.708 |
| 66 | 2.75 | 0.75 |
| 67 | 2.792 | 0.792 |
| 68 | 2.833 | 0.833 |
| 69 | 2.875 | 0.875 |
| 70 | 2.917 | 0.917 |
| 71 | 2.958 | 0.958 |
| 72 | 3.0 | 0.0 |

The table shows that the value for *Seconds* is interpolated depending on the selected frame rate.

And since *Fraction* always returns only the decimal places of that float value, logically you will always get a value between $0 - 1$ (However, it should be noted that strictly speaking you will get a value between $0-0.999...$, and this value can never be exactly $1$, because fraction of course only represents the decimal places):

[image]

And exactly this value can be used as *Factor* for curves or similar elements, which also always lies in the range $0 - 1$.

In this way, you can, for example, create a repetition in combination with the node `Sample Curve`, where a repetition occurs every second.

Another practical and simple example of use would be this one:

[image: Trimming the end point of a spiral and repeating every two seconds]
[image: Trimming the end point of a spiral and repeating every two seconds - Nodes]

<sub>(Trimming the end point of a spiral and repeating every two seconds)</sub>

Comment: +1 for the next-level illustration :)

Comment: Nice edit, just one small but: *"The table shows that the value for Seconds is interpolated[…]"* - what would the "interpolation" mean in this case? Also a number between 0 and 1 including 0 and excluding 1 can be described as a number in range $[0,1)$ but I'm always uncomfortable using this notation, not sure how many people could be confused by it.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Thanks for the edit and clarification! ...your expertise is always welcome, and in the presentation of mathematical problems you are simply more advanced than I am. ;-)